# OBSOLETE - Stack Exchange Deleted Question Viewer

Tags: script, javascript, obsolete

## READ: THIS DOES NOT WORK. It has been broken by improvements in privilege enforcement. Sorry!

## The only reason I haven't deleted this post is that it would be particularly cruel for people seeking a way to view deleted posts to be met with another inexplicably deleted question.

---

The original post is included below only for reference.

> ### Screenshot
>
> [image]
>
> ### About
>
> *Stack Exchange Deleted Question Viewer* is a user script which allows any users with at least 500 reputation to see most deleted posts, if
>   they have a link to them. It will display the post's title, content,
>   vote counts and comments. If the post has been edited at least once,
>   it will also display the author and editor.
>
> You can try this out with [a deleted question and answer of mine on
>   meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/111998), then consider taking a look at the
>   [Popular Deleted Questions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list) on meta.
>
> #### Caveats
>
> You will only be able to see answers when you use their permalink, or
>   you voted on them answer before they were deleted. This will fail for
>   locked questions, but should work for all others.
>
> This script relies on certain bugs and design features that are likely
>   to be changed at some point. I'll accommodate these changes if it's
>   possible, but it may not be.
>
> #### License
>
> Released under the [MIT Open Source License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).
>
> #### Installation
>
> [**Click here**](https://gist.github.com/raw/1361876/a2935b5bf0c5b447a8939ce8afbbea95c6b31c74/deleted.user.js) to install *Stack Exchange Deleted Question
>   Viewer*.
>
> #### Platforms
>
> - Google Chrome
> - Mozilla Firefox + [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
>
> ### Contact
>
> *Stack Exchange Deleted Question Viewer* was written me, Jeremy Banks. You can just leave feedback in the comments, but if you would like to
>   email me my address is in my profile.
>
> ### Code
>
> *Stack Exchange Deleted Question Viewer* was written in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). The source file is available
>   [here](https://raw.github.com/gist/1361876/b7bd0e2228439217d3b8e882b1f8eb9a117587ef/deleted.user.coffee).
>
> ### Oh, and...
>
> ...if any Stack Exchange folks would prefer that this be deleted, I won't object.

Comment: Really cool idea. Unfortunately I can't get it to work for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065229/how-can-i-determine-a-users-locale-or-country) question.

Comment: ...but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570213/div-does-not-recognize-jquery) one works.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I've realized that it fails on locked questions because the edit page it relies on is unavailable for them.

Comment: The next build fixes several bugs with regards to editing permissions. Unfortunately the one you're exploiting here is among them. Sorry :)

Comment: @balpha: Oh, that's good to hear. [I thought the current behaviour was a bit silly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave). :P I guess I now have an incentive to get to 10k on meta.

Comment: @balpha: The change didn't have the effect you described, it seems like 500+ rep users can still do this. See [the meta thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99593/how-is-the-editing-of-deleted-posts-supposed-to-behave/109645#109645).

Comment: Yep; I saw your update. Will look.

Comment: Really cool idea. I would test it in Greasemonkey, but don't have the required rep. points. :(

Comment: That's *genius*. Though with the current approach, you might want to check whether the user is logged in first. Anonymous users (probably low-rep too?) just get a "sod off" note instead of a forced CAPTCHA when they trip the spam filter.

Comment: Whatever happened to the version that simply posts an empty answer to force an error? 'cause I have that installed from god-knows-when and it still works.

Comment: @lunboks I didn't remember ever posting that here, I think I only mentioned it in chat or something. I thought they had fixed that; if not I might update this post later to include that version.

Comment: @JeremyBanks No idea where I got it from, but yeah, as I said it still works. Even better than it used to because empty posts no longer trip the spam filter, which means you don't have to solve a CAPTCHA every time.

Comment: Even if it worked, you’d still need the URL. `:-(`